# How to know the default path of FTP server programatically in C#

Tags: c#, ftp

I am successfully able to connect to the FTP server using C# code (TcpClient). Before I perform any operations on FTP server, I would like to know what is the default path set on the server i.e. the default path in my case is **/home**. It could be different for different server. So I would like to know the default path programatically in C# before I perform any operation on FTP server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send command "PWD". It will give you full path of the location.

Answer (score 1):

According to ftp protocol, you can send a PWD command. However, this path may has nothing to do with the host file system. A ftp server can store file in one dedicated path, and regard it as /.